# FFTW filled with zeros at the end

Tags: fft, complex-numbers, fftw

Can you help me find out why one of the FFTW's plans gives zeroes at the end of an output array? The "fftw_plan_dft_1d" yields proper result as I checked it with Matlab. The Real to Complex plan "fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d" makes some zeroes at the end. I don't understand why.

Here is the simple testing code using both plans.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fftw_complex *in, *out, *out2;
    double array[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,0.0,0.0};
    fftw_plan p, p2;

    int N = 8;

    in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    out2 = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        in[i] = i+1+0*I;
    }

    in[6] = 0+0*I;
    in[7] = 0+0*I;

    cout << "complex array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "]: " << creal(in[i]) << " + " << cimag(in[i]) << "i" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "real array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "]: " << array[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    p2 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, array, out2, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p); /* repeat as needed */
    fftw_execute(p2);

    cout << "fftw_plan_dft_1d:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "]: " << creal(out[i]) << " + " << cimag(out[i]) << "i" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "]: " << creal(out2[i]) << " + " << cimag(out2[i]) << "i" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p2);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
    fftw_free(out2);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
complex array
[0]: 1 + 0i
[1]: 2 + 0i
[2]: 3 + 0i
[3]: 4 + 0i
[4]: 5 + 0i
[5]: 6 + 0i
[6]: 0 + 0i
[7]: 0 + 0i

real array
[0]: 1
[1]: 2
[2]: 3
[3]: 4
[4]: 5
[5]: 6
[6]: 0
[7]: 0

fftw_plan_dft_1d:
[0]: 21 + 0i
[1]: -9.65685 + -3i
[2]: 3 + -4i
[3]: 1.65685 + 3i
[4]: -3 + 0i
[5]: 1.65685 + -3i
[6]: 3 + 4i
[7]: -9.65685 + 3i

fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d:
[0]: 21 + 0i
[1]: -9.65685 + -3i
[2]: 3 + -4i
[3]: 1.65685 + 3i
[4]: -3 + 0i
[5]: 0 + 0i
[6]: 0 + 0i
[7]: 0 + 0i
```

As you can see there is this strange difference between both plans and the result should be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have noted, the `fftw_plan_dft_1d` function computes the standard FFT Y<sub>k</sub> of the complex input sequence X<sub>n</sub> defined as

[image: Y_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} X_n e^{-2\pi j n k /N}]

where `j=sqrt(-1)`, for all values `k=0,...,N-1` (thus generating `N` complex outputs in the array `out`), .
You may notice that since the input happens to be real, the output exhibits Hermitian symmetry, that is for `N=8`:

```
out[4] == conj(out[4]); // the central one (out[4] for N=8) must be real
out[5] == conj(out[3]);
out[6] == conj(out[2]);
out[7] == conj(out[1]);
```

where [`conj`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/conj) is the usual complex conjugate operator.

Or course, when using `fftw_plan_dft_1d` FFTW doesn't know the input just happens to be real, and thus does not take advantage of the symmetry.

The `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d` on the other hand takes advantage of that symmetry, and as indicated in ["What FFTW Really Computes" section for "1d real data" of FFTW's documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT.html#The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT) (emphasis mine):

> As a result of this symmetry, half of the output Y is redundant (being the complex conjugate of the other half), and so the 1d r2c transforms **only output elements 0...n/2 of Y (n/2+1 complex numbers)**, where the division by 2 is rounded down.

Thus in your case with `N=8`, only `N/2+1 == 5` complex values are filled in `out2`, leaving the remaining 3 *unitilialized* (those values just happened to be zeros before the call to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d`, do not rely on them being set to 0). If needed, those other values could of course be obtained from symmetry with:

```
for (i = (N/2)+1; i<N; i++) {
  out2[i] = conj(out2[N-i]);
}
```